The routing metric is changed after a while for eth0 and eth1, automatically
I'm working on an platform that NetworkManager is gracefully embedded into its image. There are two separate eth0, and eth1, along with a 4G modem, all of which work fine. We use NetworkManager to control the network resources. We would like to privilege ethernet connections (i.e. eth0 & eth1) over the 4G modem.
Our problem is that after 3-5 seconds, the route metric is changed from what is defined in the connection (i.e. 100) to 1002 and 1003, for eth0, and eth1, respectively. But we want to have a fixed metric to use wired connections if they are available.
The funny thing is that we don't have any problem with the 4G connection, because its metric remains fixed, as is defined in the connection configuration.
We've defined all of the required parameters for the ethernet interface. Therefore the connection parameters for the ethernet links are as follows:
id=Coolon-ETH0-Connection
uuid=eb6a2892-e1ce-4616-a492-f9b105339070
type=ethernet
autoconnect-priority=9
autoconnect-retries=0
interface-name=eth0
metered=1
multi-connect=3
timestamp=1713921530

[ethernet]

[ipv4]
method=auto
route-metric=100

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
method=auto
route-metric=100

[proxy]

The routing table is as follows:
# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.247.171.133  0.0.0.0         UG    123    0        0 wwan0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    1002   0        0 eth0
10.247.171.128  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.248 U     123    0        0 wwan0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     3005   0        0 wlan0
192.150.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1002   0        0 eth0


It was because of the dhcpcd. Simply disable all of the DHCP services, when the NetworkManager is embedded in your image, due to avoid conflicts. After disabling the dhcpcd service, NetworkManager handles all the interfaces, gracefully, according to the pre-defined configuration.
